# Pasar funcion Javascript a PHP

Tags: php, javascript, replace

Hola e intentado pasar esta funcion javascript a php pero no lo e logrado e intentado con preg_replace,preg_match_all,preg_match pero no funciona

**Variable**

K("GH2H_f%60%5Db452%5DA%3D%5Ex9ge%7B5%7DDBwa2tw4C%7DdFAAp%5E%60dhbbabhcg%5E%3DBbeeae56f7b22665h_2_g44h_cb%60hfb62");

**Función**

```
K = function(a) {
    return a.replace(/[a-zA-Z]/g, function(a) {
        return String.fromCharCode(("Z" >= a ? 90 : 122) >= (a = a.charCodeAt(0) + 13) ? a : a - 26)
    })
};
```

**Resultado esperado en php**

TU2U_s%60%5Qo452%5QN%3Q%5Rk9tr%7O5%7QQOjn2gj4P%7QqSNNc%5R%60quoonoupt%5R%3QOorrnr56s7o22665u_2_t44u_po%60uso62

**Codigo en php no funciona la parte de [a-zA-Z]**

```
function K($a){
    $a = str_fromcharcode(("Z" >= $a ? 90 : 122) >= ($a = JS_charCodeAt($a) + 13) ? $a : $a - 26);
    return preg_replace('[a-zA-Z]', $a, $a);
}
```

Comment: Lo que pones en resultado es tu resultado esperado? Qué has intentado en PHP? (Comparte el código que más se haya acercado)

Comment: @JesúsFranco si amigo es el resultado esperado en php, donde tengo un problema de pasar a php es en esta parte a.replace(/[a-zA-Z]/g, function(a) he intentado con preg_match pero no se mucho en cuanto a las Expresiones regulares